# Binding source An error occurred while executing

Tags: c#, visual-studio

when I open the second form I got this error.

"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."

because I use this code

`reportoneBindingSource.DataSource=cu.reportones.ToList();`

Comment: And what does the inner exception say? Please try to provide an [mcve]. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @TobiasTheel {"Invalid column name 'timenoww5'."}

Comment: thank you @TobiasTheel i slove it